# Invalid UNC path into shortcut - Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, unc

I have to create a shortcut for someone to point and launch an application remotely from a server.

The original shortcut has a UNC path in the target and start in boxes, I need to change the UNC path but it keeps saying the path is invalid and it won't allow me to save it.

I do not have permissions to open the application myself so I cannot right click the target file location and create shortcut.

example of the path I need to change to:

Target:

```
"\\server.au\application\version\Software\Deployment\CT.EI.Start.application"
```

Start in:

```
"\\server.au\application\version\Software\Deployment"
```

I can manually go as far `\\server.com.au\application` but not any further due to permission restrictions

Do I need to get permissions to this server and file or is there another way I can put the path in the shortcut? even if its through powershell or command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it
I did actually require permissions to the file and server to be able to update the shortcut